Non-slip grip tape not lasting on worn outdoor concrete pathway. Non-slip paint?
We have a portion of very smooth and worn outdoor patio area concrete that, over 52 years, has become  like a polished surface and now is extremely slippery in the rain/when wet, a hazard for my mother or anyone. 3M outdoor grip tape has had to be reapplied about every 6 months (type 2") for several years, and no matter how it is mounted (cleaned surfaced, with or without added adhesive by 3M designed for this and according to directions, or E6000 also tried, prepped/cleaned, and weight placed atop while drying), it inevitably begins to peel up and become a trip hazard. The area sees daily sun exposure and moisture from the elements, as well as run-off from sprinklers twice a week.
At this point, after going through this process of carefully applying strips multiple times, we seek experienced advice from knowledgeable others. Here's the area below. An appealing look. We'd like to maintain this spaced strip appearance, which has a visually pleasing rhythm even if pursuing other alternatives (like grip paint or etching), over roughing up the entire area.
I haven't experience with non-slip paint, whether in a spray or brushed on. Perhaps someone here does. The brushed on variants comes in very expensive ($75-200) cans, branded Skid Grip, Tuff Grip, Dura Grip, etc. Anyone have experience with these? Does my surface look suitable for it?


I would try to find the opinion of a couple of local concrete resurfacing companies. A few minutes on the phone asking what to do for too-smooth concrete might give you some ideas. Sandblasting?

Good advice, yet I would still be interested in avoiding resurfacing the entire area, and instead replicate this look of spaced strips, either etched on the surface or by  other means. Going back, even the 3M adhesive designed for adhering the strips had little effect, and I do wonder if that was not attempted properly - either at the wrong temperature, too much, too little, not enough tackiness before laying them in, or possibly some moisture content in the concrete at the time or later. Likely using a rubber roller to press and ensure even pressure is better than putting weights on.

Went with a concrete etch solution applied first on test patch and then over the entire area. This effectively cut surface slickness on the decades old smoothened patio. Reapplied new grip strips to this surface, using 3M's recommended spray adhesive on concrete side. Once dry, a bead of 3M's edging compound was applied around strip edges, slightly overlapping strip to concrete, as per instructions.

Ever play miniature golf?
"Putting green" artificial turf is available. It's installed with an adhesive. People tromp on it all day long, and it laughs at sun, rain and snow and lasts for years. It's about as non-slip as you can get.
If safety is more important than snide comments about your choice of walking surfaces, it's a good choice.

Most things based on tape will eventually peel away. What you need is something truly bonded to the surface. Obviously the ultimate is a new layer of concrete with a rougher surface, but that is very expensive.
There are a variety of non-slip coatings designed to be painted on to concrete. They vary quite a bit in price and, likely, in durability and actual slip resistance, but that's what I would look for. There are companies (or so sayeth Google) that specialize in doing this type of work, but you can definitely get DIY cans of "non-slip paint" designed for this purpose and do it yourself.
As a comment noted, you can also grind down the existing surface to make it not as smooth. If the concrete is in good shape - i.e., where grinding won't make it start coming apart - then that may be a good solution as well, and probably longer lasting than most add-ons such as paint (and definitely longer lasting than tape).

Use to see ads for diamond pattern cutting for cow barns.  Used a grinder or concrete saw to help prevent cows from slipping on the concrete floors.

A standard part of bridge construction by highway departments includes grooving the concrete bridge deck laterally every 3/4" or so.  Partly to provide traction, and partly to reduce hydroplaning (asphalt doesn't need grooving because it's already "rough").

As you can see from the recently added photo above, the actual look of the strips, to my eye, create a pleasing visual rhythm, and so I'd like to replicate that if trying non-slip paint (by taping around the strip area before painting). I haven't experience with this non-slip paint, whether in a spray or brushed on. Perhaps someone here does, or should post a new question directly asking about this. The brushed on variant comes in very expensive ($50-200) cans, branded Skid Grip, Tuff Grip, Dura Grip, etc. Anyone have experience with these? Does my surface look suitable for it? Thank you.

@Typothalamus, these new questions could go into your original question for best visibility. IMHO: as the goal is to maximize traction and reduce the chance for an older person to slip, I would favor a complete coating over a 2" wide strip every foot or so.

A brief follow up to relay outcomes: went with a concrete etch solution applied first on test patch and then over the entire area. This effectively cut surface slickness on the decades old smoothened patio. Reapplied new grip strips, using 3M's recommended spray adhesive on concrete. Very short tack time. Once dry, 3M's edging compound was applied around the strip edges, in an overlapping bead, as per instructions. First rains yet to arrive, but shall see how it holds  and if the fine - but helpful - roughened surface in between the strips changes and whether the strips stay firmly adhered.
